# WPF icon specifications to support Windows 7 and being backward compatible

Tags: wpf, windows-7, windows-xp, icons, backwards-compatibility

I had the problem to get a `FileFormatException` as soon as I started a WPF application under Windows XP. As I [figured out](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/321285/wpf-application-fails-if-window-icon-is-a-vista-ico-file), it was caused by having image sizes bigger than 64x64 pixels in my application icon.

> If a Vista icon, that contains
>   png-image, is used as Window.Icon the
>   application fails to launch with an
>   FileFormatException.
>
> Make sure the icon has max size 64x64
>   pixels.  It can still be 32 bit (using
>   alpha channel).

Is this really the only workaround to not have image sizes bigger than 64x64 pixels in my icon? Isn't there a way to support Windows 7 icons at its highest resolution (256x256 pixels) and being backward compatible to Windows XP at the same time?

I'm aware of the icon specifications for the different single Windows OSs, but is there also a specification of how to support Windows 7 and being backward compatible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wow, that's just nuts. I think you've just inspired me to hold off switching to WPF a little longer. Oh yeah, and +1.

Comment: Note that this is the _Window_ icon at the left of the title bar, not the application icon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a png-image as the windows icon (XAML or code) and set in the project-settings the real icon-file with the high resolution-content for the executable file (project-icon). Windows XP will accept your Window-instances and window 7 has it's highres-icons.

Comment: It's a solution, not the one I hoped for but a solution and so far it seems the only one. So I'm accepting that. Thank you!